# How do I get field values from masterRow

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

Once I get the e.masterRow in the detailExpand event, how do I get the field values from teh masterRow in Kendo UI Grid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [dataItem](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#dataitem) method which will return the data item to which the row is bound to:

```
var masterDataItem = masterGrid.dataItem(e.masterRow);

console.log(masterDataItem.field1);
```